# How to achieve server side pagination functionality on client side cache data in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am facing the problem with jqgrid pagination. 
I have a json objects in client side cache (in javascript object).
My jqgrid data type is local.
I cannot set the whole cache to jqgrid.
Let say in cache 1000 records, and on first load, I wants to provide 10 records only and when user press next button, I will read the next 10 records from cache and populate the jqgrid.
But when I set data type local and provide the 10 records on first load then jqgrid pagination show 1-10 of 10 only (instead of 1-10 of 1000).

Can you please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks & Regards,
Brijesh Baser

Comment: 1000 rows can be paged by jqGrid very quickly. You don't need to do anything. Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-4000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) which use 4000 rows, 13 columns and 20 rows in the page and [another one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-40000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) with 40000 rows. You can try to sort, filter or to use paging. You will see relatively good performance for modern web browsers.

Comment: Thanks Oleg for quick reply. 1000 records, I just use as an Example.
But my requirement is on first load, it should load 10 records and when user press next button, we should read the data from cache and populate not to do by jqgrid itself.
But when I choose data type local and provide 10 records on first load the pagination show 1-10 of 10. it should be display 1-10 of 1000 and every page next, I should populate the data into jqgrid.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't follow you. I try to explain that 1000 rows is *not so large number of items*. Loading of all 1000 *at once* and local paging will be more quickly as loading of every page from the server. You can try to measure the time of initial loading of 1000 rows from the server (especially if you use gzip in HTTP) and then paging locally with paging on the server. Sending the request to the server, processing the request and  returning the data to the client will be take typically more time as local paging in JavaScript. So for the user local paging will be more responsible.

Comment: in my case, I am reading the data from indexed db and there are millions of records. I cannot fetch all records from indexed db and give it to jqgrid.
indexed db is local database at client side. For this, there is no server interaction required. So on first load, I will read the 10  records from indexed db and populate the jqgrid. When user press next button, I will read next 10 records from indexed db and populate the jqgrid.
But my problem is when 10 records provide jqgrid on first load, it will shows 1-10 of 10. I wants 1-10 of (total no Of record in indexed db). 
data type is "Local".